# Replace all values of NULL in a list of List to something else/ list of list with varying lengths

Tags: r, list, plyr, nested-lists

I have a list of lists that I need to convert into the correspond dataframe.

The position of the rows is important so that I can link them to another item later on.  I tried one approach where I make it into a dataframe, but I can't do that because of some rows being NULL.

```
  first = c(1,2,3)
  second = c(1,2)
  problemrows = NULL

  mylist = list(first,second,problemrows)
  #mylist   - should turn into a dataframe with each row being same order as        the list of lists.  NULL value would be a null row

 library(plyr) # doesn't work because of NULLs above
    t(plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(mylist, t)))
  ## help^^^   Ideally the row that doesn't work would just be a null row or the new dataframe would remove these NULL lists as rows and instead assign appropriate row#s to everything else to make up for what was skipped.


     # other approach - change all the NULL list of lists to something like -999 which is another fix.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
first = c(1,2,3)
second = c(1,2)
problemrows = NULL

mylist = list(first,second,problemrows)

mylist <- sapply(mylist, function(x) ifelse(x == "NULL", NA, x))

library(plyr) # doesn't work because of NULLs above
t(plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(mylist, t)))
```